# Kotlin `object` initialization order leads to unexpected null instance

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, null, jvm, heap-memory

Consider the following code:

```kotlin
sealed class DataType<T : Any> {
    abstract fun inputToType(input: String): T
    abstract fun typeToSql(value: T): String

    companion object {
        val all = listOf(StringDt, LongDt)
    }
}

object StringDt : DataType<String>() {
    override fun inputToType(input: String) = input
    override fun typeToSql(value: String) = "\"${value}\""
}

object LongDt : DataType<Long>() {
    override fun inputToType(input: String) = input.toLong()
    override fun typeToSql(value: Long) = value.toString()
}

val dataTypeList = listOfNotNull(StringDt, LongDt)

println(dataTypeList)
println(DataType.all)
```

Things to consider:

- `object` as per [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) (and my understanding as well) is singleton and always instantiated
- the two objects (`StringDt` and `LongDt`) are quite similar

The result of `println(DataType.all)` shows that one of the objects are not initialized. How is that possible? I would expect all the list elements to be initialized.

IntelliJ version: CE 2020.2
Kotlin plugin version: 1.4.0-release-IJ2020.2-1

Here's a [running example](https://pl.kotl.in/wsyk8uhFQ) which shows that the static list has a null element, while the non-static one contains both objects initialized.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. https://pl.kotl.in/Z7P1uYn6_

Comment: Yeah, it's odd. In another list where I use these datatypes, `LongDt` is also presented.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I adjusted your example: https://pl.kotl.in/uOCRdT1U1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens due to cyclical static initializations. It's pretty hard to explain this problem in two words but you can read about it [here](https://medium.com/livefront/kotlin-a-tale-of-static-cyclical-initialization-3aea530d2053).

To fix this behavior you can change `all` initialization like this:

```kotlin
val all by lazy { listOf(StringDt, LongDt) }
```